Need replace some value with new one based on common grouping
I have table A
with 9 records
text, value, dt
1, 1, 2024-01-01
1, 2, 2024-02-01
1, 3, 2024-03-01
1+1, 4, 2024-04-01
1+1, 5, 2024-05-01
2, 6, 2024-05-01
2+1, 7, 2024-06-01
3, 8, 2024-01-01
3, 9, 2024-06-01

I need get 6 records based on the latest date where +1, if no data for +1 then value2 should be null
text, value, dt, value2
1, 1, 2024-01-01, 5
1, 2, 2024-02-01, 5
1, 3, 2024-03-01, 5
2, 6, 2024-05-01, 7
3, 8, 2024-01-01, null
3, 8, 2024-06-01, null


here is one way :
with cte as (
  select t1.text 
     , value 
     , row_number() over (partition by text order by dt desc) as rn
  from my_table t1
  where t1.text like '%+1'
) 

select t1.* , cte.value as value2 
from my_table t1 
left join cte 
  on concat(t1.text, '+1') = cte.text 
  and cte.rn = 1
where t1.text not like '%+1'

output:



text
value
dt
value2




1
1
2024-01-01
5


1
2
2024-02-01
5


1
3
2024-03-01
5


2
6
2024-05-01
7


3
8
2024-01-01
null


3
9
2024-06-01
null



